# Current User not being set?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

So I am having an issue with my code. My signup page grabs the user data. It gets the username, location, and profile pic. Everything works right it seems everything is being saved to firebase. However when the account is created and I go to the user profile everything seems to be nil.

This is my function that handles the sign up.

```
 @objc func handleSignUp(){
        // first we cant to take sure that all of the fields are filled
        let bio: String = ""
        var profilePic: String = ""

        // will take the user selected image and load it to firebase
        let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
 let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child("\(imageName).PNG")
        if let userImage = selectedImageFromPicker,let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(userImage, 0.1){

            storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print(error ?? "")
                    return
                }
                 profilePic = (metadata?.downloadURL()!.absoluteString)!
                guard let username = self.nameTextField.text,
                    let confirmPassword = self.confirmPasswordTextField.text,
                    let email = self.emailTextField.text,
                    let password = self.passwordTextField.text,
                    !username.isEmpty,
                    !email.isEmpty,
                    !password.isEmpty,
                    !confirmPassword.isEmpty
                    else {

                        print("Required fields are not all filled!")
                        return
                }
                if self.validateEmail(enteredEmail:email) != true{
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please Enter A Valid Email", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

                // will make sure user is validated before it even tries to create user

                // will make sure the password and confirm password textfields have the same value if so it will print an error
                if self.passwordTextField.text != self.confirmPasswordTextField.text {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Passwords Don't Match", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }

                // will authenticate a user into the authentication services with an email and passowrd
                AuthService.createUser(controller: self, email: email, password: password) { (authUser) in
                    guard let firUser = authUser else {
                        return
                    }
                    //will add user to the database
                    print(profilePic)
                    print(username)
                    UserService.create(firUser, username: username , profilePic: profilePic , bio: bio, location: self.userLocation!) { (user) in
                        guard let user = user else {
                            print("User successfully loaded into firebase db")
                            return
                        }
                        // will set the current user for userdefaults to work
                        print(user.profilePic)
                        print(user.username)

                        User.setCurrent(user, writeToUserDefaults: true)
                        // self.delegate?.finishSigningUp()

                        self.finishSigningUp()


                    }
                }

        })
        }
    }
```

This is my viewdidload for the profile controller. When I print out the user here everything is nil.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            let user = self.user ?? User.current

            profileHandle = UserService.observeProfile(for: user) { [unowned self](ref, user, events) in
                self.profileRef = ref
                self.user = user
                self.userEvents = events
                // self.jobs = allJobs
                // self.reciepts = allReciepts

                // print(self.userEvents)
                //  print(self.reciepts)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }

            }
```

This handles the transition to the homepage.

```
  func finishSigningUp() {
        print("Finish signing up from signup view controller")
        print("Attempting to return to root view controller")
        let homeController = HomeViewController()
        //should change the root view controller to the homecontroller when done signing up
        self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeController
        self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

My home view controller controls the navigation of these throguh a snapcaht style swiping which is controlled using an array of view controllers. Like so

```
 lazy var viewControllerList: [UIViewController] = {
        let homeFeedController = HomeFeedController()
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeFeedController)
//        let navController = ScrollingNavigationController(rootViewController: homeFeedController)


        let profileView = ProfileeViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        let profileViewNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: profileView)

        let searchController = EventSearchController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        let searchNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: searchController)

        return [searchNavController,navController,profileViewNavController]
    }()
```

Obseverprofile function

```
// will observe the user object in the database for any changes and make sure that they are updated
    static func observeProfile(for user: User, completion: @escaping (DatabaseReference, User?, [Event]) -> Void) -> DatabaseHandle {
        // 1
        let userRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(user.uid)

        // 2
        return userRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            // 3
            guard let user = User(snapshot: snapshot) else {
                return completion(userRef, nil, [])
            }

          //  print(user)
            // 4
            Events(for: user, completion: { events in
                // 5
                completion(userRef, user, events)
            })
        })
    }
```

User Model

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase.FIRDataSnapshot

class User : NSObject {

    //User variables
    let uid : String
    let username : String?
    let profilePic: String?
    var location: String?
    var isFollowed = false
    let bio: String?
    var dictValue: [String : Any] {
        return ["username" : username as Any,
                "profilePic" : profilePic as Any,
                "Bio" : bio as Any, "location": location as Any]
    }

    //Standard User init()
    init(uid: String, username: String, profilePic: String, bio: String, location: String = "") {
        self.uid = uid
        self.username = username
        self.profilePic = profilePic
        self.bio = bio
    self.location = location
        super.init()
    }

    //User init using Firebase snapshots
    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any],
            let username = dict["username"] as? String,
            let profilePic = dict["profilePic"] as? String,
            let bio = dict["bio"] as? String,
        let location = dict["location"] as? String
            else { return nil }
        self.uid = snapshot.key
        self.location = location
        self.username = username
        self.profilePic = profilePic
        self.bio = bio
    }

    //UserDefaults
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let uid = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "uid") as? String,
            let username = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "username") as? String,
            let profilePic = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "profilePic") as? String,
            let bio = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "bio") as? String,
            let location = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "location") as? String
            else { return nil }

        self.uid = uid
        self.username = username
        self.profilePic = profilePic
        self.bio = bio
        self.location = location
        super.init()
    }


    init?(key: String, postDictionary: [String : Any]) {
        //var dict : [String : Any]
        //print(postDictionary as? [String:])
        let dict = postDictionary
        print(dict)
        let profilePic = dict["profilePic"] as? String ?? ""
        let bio = dict["bio"] as? String ?? ""
        let username = dict["username"] as? String ?? ""
        let location = dict["location"] as? String ?? ""

        self.uid = key
        self.location = location
        self.profilePic = profilePic
        self.username = username
        self.bio = bio
    }


    //User singleton for currently logged user
    private static var _current: User?

    static var current: User {
        guard let currentUser = _current else {
            fatalError("Error: current user doesn't exist")
        }

        return currentUser
    }

    class func setCurrent(_ user: User, writeToUserDefaults: Bool = true) {
        print(user)
        print("")
        if writeToUserDefaults {
            let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: user)

            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "currentUser")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }

        _current = user
        print(_current)
    }
}

extension User: NSCoding {
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(uid, forKey: "uid")
        aCoder.encode(username, forKey: "username")
        aCoder.encode(profilePic, forKey: "profilePic")
        aCoder.encode(bio, forKey: "bio")
        aCoder.encode(location, forKey: "location")

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you called the login function? I see create, validate, observe but I do not see a login call to firebase to actually log the user in.

Comment: well my function writes the current user to user defaults and then send them to the homeviewController after setting it as the rootViewController

Comment: How are you going from signup page to profile page , can you show the code for that?

Comment: see edits please @3stud1ant3

Comment: so you are saying that `user` is nil in this statement `self.user = user` , right?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I am saying @3stud1ant3

Comment: Is the `self.user` nil here as well `let user = self.user ?? User.current` and what does this method do: `UserService.observeProfile` ?

Comment: see edits again please @3stud1ant3

Comment: what does this statement print `print(user)` in your `UserService.observeProfile` method? , please check if it is nil?

Comment: This line `self.user ?? User.current` is this a typo?! because `User.current` is wrong. `User` with capital `U` means the *type* `User` it **doesn't** mean *an instance of type* of `User`. You should edit it to `self.user ?? user.current`. It's actually odd that it compiles with this. Can you also share how does your `User` class/struct look like?

Comment: see edits please @Honey

Comment: @3stud1ant3 it doesnt seem to be nil

Comment: The issue seems to be originating from your 'Obseverprofile function'. From there the `user` you do also have a possibility of returnin `nil`. Make sure you do reach lines 4 and 5. My guess is that you reach the else statement of line 3 ie you hit `return completion(userRef, nil, [])` which obviously returns `nil` for 'user'. I'm not sure buy maybe you made a mistake and thought in `UserService.observeProfile(for: user) { [unowned self](ref, user, events)` expression, the `user` is coming from `(for: user)` and isn't coming from `{ [unowned self](ref, user, events)`

Comment: ouch didnt even notice that

Comment: In your User class you have inconsistent spellings of a key:  "Bio" in dictValue which is presumably used when saving, and "bio" in in your init(snapshot).   The five way guard statement will fail if any of those expressions return nil, which will happen trying to find "bio" in a dictionary containing "Bio".  @Honey explained what will happen after that ...

Comment: thanks so much I appreciate that @ozzieozumo wouldnt have noticed that either